# nodejs - how to get cookie in ws (einaros)

Tags: node.js, websocket

In socketio, I can easily get cookie with `socket.handshake.headers.cookie`. How could I do the same thing in `ws`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this one: `ws.upgradeReq.headers.cookie`.

Answer (score 3):

I was using client.upgradeReq.headers.cookie, but that broke suddenly.
I found cookies at request.headers.cookie:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(client, request))
{
  ...
  var cookies = {};
  //Not working any more
  //if(client.upgradeReq.headers.cookie) request.headers.cookie.split(';')...
  //This works
  if(request.headers.cookie) request.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(cookie)
  {
    var parts = cookie.match(/(.*?)=(.*)$/);
    var name = parts[1].trim();
    var value = (parts[2] || '').trim();
    cookies[ name ] = value;
  });
  ...
```